# How to apply Rubio Monocoat and Black Bison Wax to white oak

Tags: finishing, furniture, oak, wax

I love the look of black bison wax on oak as a way to really bring out the grain. (see example photo)

Until now I've only used rubio monocoat as a finish. It's pretty much impossible to mess up and it provides a good level of protection for the stuff I'm building. Now I'm working on a white oak bookcase and want to incorporate black bison wax + my usual rubio monocoat.

Can hardwax oil finishes (like Rubio) and furniture wax (Black Bison Wax) be combined? In what order should they be applied to the work piece?

[image]

Comment: Doesn't Rubio emphasise that Monocoat has to go on to clean bare wood? That pretty much tells you what you need to do right there, and also standard coloured waxes aren't fussed about the surface they go on to.

Comment: Thanks, that's good to know about waxes in general.

Comment: Yeah waxes don't care what they're applied to; we can sort of see an extreme example of this with car waxes, which of course are applied to a fully built up finish that goes way beyond what would be on most furniture. Anyway, you're well set up here to self-Answer this which'll give you extra points (and potentially a bronze badge if it gets three upvotes which it should if you set out to write it as a good Answer – quote something from Rubio, include the link to the source and you should be good to go).